# How to increase the render distance in command & conquer generals

Tags: command-and-conquer-zero-hour

When you use a large resolution you will get the effect that not all visible ground textures will be rendered. Is there a way to increase this render distance?

[image: problem]

Comment: Try out http://www.wsgf.org/dr/command-conquer-generals

Comment: Well, it works but could you gove it as an answer? So I can accept it.

Comment: At this point you should just write your own answer and outline which steps worked for you. Link-only answers are highly frowned upon because links can easily go dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do this. However it is possible to render the full map.

You can do it this way:

1. Go to your generals install directory
2. Find the INI directory
3. Open `GameData.ini` (download from https://www.moddb.com/games/cc-generals/downloads/ini-files)
4. Add or change `DrawEntireTerrain = Yes`